# Count 'n' records from table between 'now()' and date from secondary table - then calculate

Tags: sql, vba, function, ms-access

I have a database to track rewards purchases for our customers.  Our customers come in, make a purchase, and we log it into this rewards database.  When a customer meets the requirements (see below) for a rewards "issue", the database will "issue" the rewards to the customer.  Next time the customer makes a purchase, we will see $XX.XX rewards in our database and apply that discount to their purchase.

The biggest thing I'm struggling with is a method to accomplish this that 1) won't slow down the database, and 2) can be accomplished in the background, when the db user is working.

**Currently, the requirements are:**

- Six purchases within a calendar year.
- The Six purchases have to occur on DIFFERENT dates.  Purchases that occur on the same day are tallied as part of the same purchase
- These requirements (6 purchases in 6 visits) are kept as options in `tblOptions`

I'm trying to assemble a procedure (a function I could call throughout the db to perform the "math" here each time the user completes a task) in order to check if there are `n` purchases since the beginning of the calendar year (based on `NumVisits` & `NumPurchases` in `tblOptions`) OR since the last date rewards had been issued (this date is in `qryLastRewardIssuedDate`) from `tbPurchases` (yes, I left out an "l" on accident - I'll fix it later).

**Goals:**

- Retrieve how many purchases had been made since `qryLastRewardIssued.IssueDate`
- Verify they were made on separate days and in the current calendar year
- IF the requirements above have been met, then calculate a percentage of their total purchases based on the setting in `tblOptions.PerDiscount`

**Here are my relationships:**
[image: Table Relationships]

**HISTORY:**

This started with me attempting to create a simple query to pull the number of purchases.  I wanted to try to accomplish this using queries, but after some thought I decided it might be more efficient to create a procedure I can call each time the user performs an action.  My queries, unfortunately, haven't been working out for me and I've struggled with this entire process.  I'm really rusty with Access (as evident by my Stack Overflow history) and I'm honestly not that great with it to begin with.  I'm experienced with Access and have designed several databases in the past, but those all were simple "put data in, review data later" databases.  This one actually needs to process math procedures on a regular basis as it's being used.

Since this started with a query to just pull the number of purchases, here's the SQL statement I've been using (which doesn't give an error, but it always returns no results):

```
SELECT Count(tbPurchases.MemberID) AS CountOfMemberID, Count(tbPurchases.PurchaseDate) AS NumOfPurchases
FROM tbPurchases INNER JOIN qryLastRewardIssuedDate ON tbPurchases.MemberID = qryLastRewardIssuedDate.CustomerID
HAVING (((Count(tbPurchases.PurchaseDate)) Between [qryLastRewardIssuedDate]![IssueDate] And Now()));
```

And here is the SQL to my query, `qryLastRewardIssuedDate`:

```
SELECT tblRewards.CustomerID, Last(tblRewards.IssueDate) AS LastOfIssueDate
FROM tblRewards
GROUP BY tblRewards.CustomerID;
```

I know there's not a whole lot to go by here, and I'm sorry for that.  I haven't had any epiphanies to lead me in the right direction yet.  I hoping y'all can help me with that.  Thank you!

**EDIT:** 
After playing with your SQL statement a little bit (and fixing the aliases mentioned in the comment), here is what I'm up to:

```
SELECT q.MemberID, Max(q.PurchaseDate) AS MaxOfPurchaseDate
FROM (SELECT p.MemberID, p.PurchaseDate FROM tbPurchases p WHERE p.PurchaseDate >= Dateserial(2012,1,1)
  AND p.PurchaseDate > (SELECT Max(r.IssueDate) FROM tblRewards r WHERE r.CustomerID = p.MemberID))  AS q
GROUP BY q.MemberID
HAVING (((Count(*))>=(SELECT Last(o.NumPurchases) AS LastOfNumPurchases FROM tblOptions o)));
```

This accounts for the variable number of purchases, too.  One issue I'm having is outputting the proper cost of the purchase (`tbPurchases.PurchaseAmount`).  I get the same result down the query when I use this SQL:

```
SELECT q.MemberID, Max(q.PurchaseDate) AS MaxOfPurchaseDate, Last(tbPurchases.PurchaseAmount) AS LastOfPurchaseAmount
FROM (SELECT p.MemberID, p.PurchaseDate FROM tbPurchases AS p WHERE p.PurchaseDate >= Dateserial(2012,1,1)       AND p.PurchaseDate > (SELECT Max(r.IssueDate) FROM tblRewards r WHERE r.CustomerID = p.MemberID))  AS q, tbPurchases
GROUP BY q.MemberID
HAVING (((Count(*))>=(SELECT Last(o.NumPurchases) AS LastOfNumPurchases FROM tblOptions o)));
```

Which, I assume could be a JOIN problem or possibly the fact that I need to alias `tbPurchases.PurchaseAmount`?  I'm not entirely sure.

Additionally, I'm not entirely sure how to verify the purchases were made on separate days right now.  Any ideas?

**EDIT 2 - Sample Data:**

`tblMembers`:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ First Name ║ Last Name ║
╠════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ Jason      ║ Something ║
║  2 ║ Jimmy      ║ Carter    ║
║  3 ║ Ronald     ║ Reagan    ║
║  4 ║ Ronald     ║ McDonald  ║
╚════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

`tblOptions`:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ NumVisits ║ NumPurchases ║ PerDiscount ║
╠════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║         6 ║            6 ║ 10.00%      ║
╚════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

`tblRewards`:

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦
║ ID ║ CustomerID ║ IssueDate  ║ IssueAmount ║ 
╠════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬
║  1 ║      24544 ║ 7/22/2011  ║ $100.00     ║
║  2 ║      24557 ║ 6/27/2018  ║ $100.00     ║
║  3 ║      25012 ║ 11/23/2019 ║ $46.63      ║
║  4 ║      28227 ║ 11/11/2019 ║ $40.35      ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩
```

`tbPurchases`:

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID ║ MemberID ║ PurchaseDate ║ PurchaseAmount ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╣
║  1 ║    29792 ║ 2/25/2013    ║ $37.99         ║
║  2 ║    24586 ║ 1/3/2019     ║ $114.99        ║
║  3 ║    26505 ║ 1/3/2019     ║ $7.96          ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╝
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**
The idea here is to check the db for customers who have made `n` purchases (from `tblOptions.NumPurchases` - currently 6) in the current calendar year.  The data in the database doesn't have a whole lot, but I did add some purchases just to test it out for this purpose.

If there have been the correct number of purchases in the current calendar year, then it will calculate the total amount the customer spent on those `n` purchases and using `tblOptions.PerDiscount` it will calculate the amount of "rewards" the customer is entitled to on their next visit.

Then is when the procedure comes in.  I would like to try to create a function that can accomplish these calculations throughout the database.  Adding it to other actions, such as adding new customers, or entering a purchase by a current customer.  And, most importantly, when the database opens and closes.  These are all easily accomplish by creating a procedure I can call repeatedly.  But I'm having trouble getting these SQL queries to cooperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do **not** use `Last` to obtain the most recent `IssueDate`: when used with an unordered dataset, `Last` will merely return the last record encountered by the database engine when evaluating the query, which will not necessarily be the last record in the dataset.

This is also noted in the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/first-last-functions-acd76019-c37f-432d-9807-4fc63cac1db5):

> These functions return the value of a specified field in the first or last record, respectively, of the result set returned by a query. **If the query does not include an ORDER BY clause, the values returned by these functions will be arbitrary because records are usually returned in no particular order.**

Instead, you should use `max` to obtain the latest `IssueDate` for each `CustomerID`:

```
select
    r.customerid,
    max(r.issuedate) as lastissued
from
    tblrewards r
group by
    r.customerid
```

---

For the overall goal, I might suggest a query such as the following:

```
select
    q.memberid
from
    (
        select distinct
            p.memberid,
            p.purchasedate
        from
            tbpurchases p
        where
            p.purchasedate >= dateserial(year(date()),1,1) and
            p.purchasedate >
            (
                select
                    max(r.issuedate)
                from
                    tblrewards r
                where
                    r.customerid = p.memberid
            )
    ) q
group by    
    q.memberid
having
    count(*) >= 6
```

Note that the above is entirely untested.

Comment: Without sample data, it is difficult to advise what the problem is.

Comment: No, just update your question with the minimal amount of data for a handful of records with which to test, along with the result that you expect to obtain.

Comment: The `tblMember` IDs do no seem to correlate with the `MemberID` in the other tables?